# GFCI in garage keeps tripping when I turn on kitchen lights

Tags: gfci, troubleshooting

The GFCI outlet in my garage keeps tripping whenever we turn on the kitchen lights.  When it trips, two cable TV boxes in the living room and one bedroom also lose signal.  I press the button (sometimes I have to press it 2-3 times to make it stay in) and the cable TV boxes re-acquire the cable signal.  I have not been able to identify any other impact by the tripping.  Does anyone have any idea what I can do to troubleshoot or fix this issue?

Comment: So the boxes lose signal, but do they lose power?.

Comment: It sounds like you might need more help, than can be provided through the internet. My advice would be to contact a local licensed Electrician.  This problem will likely require somebody to be on site, so they can directly evaluate the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem normal that a GFCI in your garage should control outlets in the living room and bedroom.  Usually, they are connected to outlets in bathrooms and/or kitchens.  Nevertheless, you should try unplugging the two cable boxes and see if the problem persists.  If it does, then the kitchen lights need to be investigated.  If it does not, then you need to investigate the outlets that are used by the cable boxes. If you are comfortable around electricity, you can take apart the outlets and/or the light fixtures and look for wiring problems such as loose wires, worn insulation, etc.  If you are not, then you should call an electrician.